# What is the proper preposition for this question?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Fill in the blank with appropriate preposition and give a reason:

> What is the time ***_*____** your watch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and most correct choice for the blank is the prepositional phrase, *[according to](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1219567#m_en_us1219567)*:

> What is the time *according to* your watch?

The New Oxford American Dictionary defines *according to* as:

> as stated by or in

---

If you only had one-word prepositions to choose from, then *[on](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1273365?rskey=5dhKub&result=3#m_en_us1273365)* would be your next best option, although I would not consider it as formal:

> What is the time *on* your watch?

Also, using *on* is a loose way of saying:

> What time has your watch?

---

You could also use *[by](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1229806#m_en_us1229806)*, although this usage is not common in this context:

> What is the time *by* your watch?

One of the definitions of *by*, as given by the New Oxford American Dictionary, is:

> concerning; according to

Comment: I find _What time has your watch?_ to be odd.  I would say _What time does your watch have?_.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: I was also going to include that as an alternative, but I figured it did not matter. Both are fine. *What time has your watch?* sounds smoother, in my opinion, and I'd be more likely to say that than the alternative ending with *have*.

Comment: "What time has your watch?" is not AmE. Sounds a bit 'Harry Potter' to me (that is, sounds a bit British, but I can't tell if it's truly BrE or just scripted from the media)

Comment: @Mitch: Probably not, haha. Although I speak American English with a generic American accent now, I had a heavy British influence growing up, so traces still show. But I'm sure we'd both agree that neither sentence is common in regular conversation among native speakers.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Between "What time has your watch?" and the transformed "What time does your watch have?", though both follow the normal rule-book rules, in AmE neither is preferred. But there are situations where an AmE would say the second: "I think my watch is slow...what time does -your- watch have?", and I can't think of any context where an AmE speaker would utter the first.

Comment: @Mitch: Indeed. I'd concede *What time has your watch* is quite formal, and one would be hard-pressed to find this in regular conversation in the US, or even elsewhere. I wrote it offhand as the formal equivalent of *What's the time on your watch*.

Comment: Sorry for pursuing this so relentlessly...my commenting is just to help make ESL learners (or anyone learning a foreign language for that matter) aware that 'grammatical' and 'following rules' and 'sounding native' can all be different. Also, some rules only apply in certain contexts. It would really stick in my craw if people started saying things like 'What time have you?', that's all, however grammatical it is (and I wouldn't have a problem if people started saying a lot 'What time does your watch have?' though I would wonder why they're so interested in my watch).

Comment: @Mitch: No worries. As another user, Callithumpian, said, "[Challenges keep answer quality high.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/single-word-for-village-of-dreams/18240#18240)" Also, I would agree that *What time have you?* is not only weird, but also ambiguous. How many ever say, *What time do you have?* for that matter?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the technically correct answer is "on," but the question itself is not idiomatic English. That is, you'd never see it in print or hear it spoken by a native speaker. More common would be:

1. What time is it?
2. What time does your watch say?
3. Do you have the time?
4. Can you tell me what time it is?
5. What time does your watch have?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are trying to say

> What is the time *on* your watch?

would be the same as asking, "what time do you have?"

> What is the time *by* your watch?

would, while sounding a little awkward, be specifying that I seek the time according to *your* watch rather than someone else's.

> What is the time *of* your watch?

would, while also sounding awkward, be asking when the watch was made.

I expect you want the first one, though I might suggest you rephrase saying:

> What time does your watch have?

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: I heard someone saying in a movie "you are late"in reply the guy said "not by my watch"what do you say now?

Comment: As I mentioned above, "Not *by* my watch," means "Well, according to *your* watch I may be late, but according to *my* watch, I'm not late.  The second guy was insisting on his promptness by suggesting his watch stated he was on time, though the first guy's watch may have been fast, indicating he was late.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> What is the time *according to* your watch?

That implies that you suspect that watch may disagree with someone else's (either because it is wrong, or the other watch is).

Answer (score 0):

You want "**on**."  As in,

> What is the time on your watch?