# Single word for "village of dreams"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can someone suggest a single word for "village of dreams" in any language except the word "leonesse" as it has connotation of a place known for wines.

Comment: What sort of "dreams"? Daydreams, good fortunes, idleness, sleep?

Comment: Are you asking us to refer you to an extant word or would you like us to coin a word for you?

Comment: I think you mean 'Lyonesse', the land to which King Arthur was taken, now sunk beneath the waves.

Answer (score 10):

Camelot, El Dorado, Shangri-La, Bali Hai and Brigadoon are some well-known mythical perfect places....

Comment: Nice list. I'd add [Brigadoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadoon) as well.

Comment: Excellent idea.  Consider it done.  :-)

Comment: Nice list, too. +1

Comment: The last three aren't myths.  They are simply inventions of 20th Century authors: James Hilton (for his novel of that name), Richard Rodgers (for the song of that name in his musical *South Pacific*), and Alan Jay Lerner (for his musical of that name).  Brigadoon was original Germelshausen, a German village, but when Lerner was writing, in the mid-1940s, he decided to change it to Scotland, for some reason.

Comment: Shangri-La wasn't invented by James Hilton, just [misspelled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shambhala). You could add the correct spelling, Shambhala, to the list.

Comment: Brigadoon is the Bridge of Doon in Ayrshire, Scotland. Not a myth.

Answer (score 5):

How about,

> Utopia

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily consider *utopia* a *village* of dreams. To me, *utopia* connotes a perfect or ideal *world*, not a village. Plus, *utopia* is not necessarily everyone's dream :)

Comment: I agree it's not the end-all-be-all answer to the question. But I do think the list would be incomplete without it.

Comment: True. Could certainly be appropriate in some contexts. We also do not know what the asker is really after. +1

Answer (score 4):

How about *dreamland*, *wonderland* or *fantasyland*?

Comment: I would consider *dreamland* a *land* of dreams, not a *village*!

Comment: @Jimi: I agree, but Camelot is a castle, Eldorado is a city, Shangri-La is a valley, and Bali Hai is an island. I was following others' lead in interpreting the question loosely.

Comment: Sorry if I appear to have picked on your answer for no reason. *Land* screamed at me, and I wasn't paying enough attention to other answers. Of your three suggestions, though, *fantasyland* would certainly be my pick. (*Wonderland* also works.) [+1] *Dreamland* usually refers to where dreams take place, or figuratively used to mean *asleep*, as in: *I tried to wake him up, but he was far gone, away in dreamland.*

Comment: @Jimi: No worries. Challenges keep answer quality high.

Comment: For me, *wonderland* will always refer to the [Wonderland Murders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonderland_murders).  But maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

How about "avalon"? It's taken to mean something like that in English literature.

Answer (score 1):

How about '***Dreamsville***'?  Henry Mancini wrote a song about that place.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go medieval ... *Cockaigne* or *Cockayne*

When said (if it is said) it is usually "The Land of Cockaigne"

Comment: Unfortunately, this *really* doesn't work when said aloud. :/

Comment: Yeah, top ten innocuous words that should never be said in front of the immature ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can I interest you in *Oneiropolis*?